# Is it possible to change the default WP post table's data source?

Tags: posts, wp-list-table

I was wondering if there was a function to change the default MySQL data source (to JSON or REST data) for a post table without having to make a custom Wp_List_table?

I know how to make a custom WP LIST TABLE to run on JSON DATA, but I am want to just change the source tech.

Comment: No, there isn't. WordPress is based on PHP and MySQL. They're the core technologies, and a huge amount of the post-related functions and functionality depend on there being a SQL database, and the core tables. If you're going to rewrite that whole component then there'd be no reason to use WordPress. Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: Just to render the default post table from a different source, but keeping any updating with the default mysql

Comment: I want to create a JSON from the MySQL data and render the post table with the JSON data for speed, but update with the default WP functions, then repeat.